# facebook php SDK on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I use the PHP SDK for creating a facebook app. It works fine on all the browsers, but not on Chrome. 
I tested the adding of :

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
```

at the begining of the facebook.php file, but in vain.

I know this topic has been covered in some posts on SO, but my problem seems different : on chrome when I load the facebook app I have a grey page with this icon [image]

Is the problem related with https things ? With cookie things ?

More than that, when I use the JS sdk the same issue occurs.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Anything happening when you hover over or click on this ominous icon …?

Comment: No, nothing happened. I have a grey iframe and, at its center, the icon.

Comment: Then you’ll need to be more specific – what does “doesn’t work” mean, and can you tell us the address of your app?

Comment: When I say "doesn't work" (which is obviously not precise :) I mean that on the other browsers, the prompt of the app authentication appears for example. And, if I accept the app, a page is dispayed.
The app is here https://apps.facebook.com/villes_de_france_iii

Comment: The canvas URL of your app is https://www.jeuxgeo.com/facebook_2013/_app/towns_fr_3/, and when I call that directly in Chrome I get a warning that the certificate you’re using is not trustworthy … (Chrome does not seem to show that info for framed pages – using Firefox, you can see that warning directly inside the Facebook iframe.)

Comment: This was my conclusion too : a problem with the SSL. Thank you CBroe, now I'm sure of it.
Bye